# NGINX does not serve the collected static files

Tags: django, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running a dockerized Django application on an AWS EC2 instance, and the page loads without the static files, even though NGINX has them collected. I find this pretty strange, as it had not happened to me until now (at least on my local machine). It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me solve this issue.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: bash -c "
      python manage.py makemigrations &&
      python manage.py migrate &&
      python manage.py creategroups &&
      python manage.py initializesuperuser &&
      python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
      daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80 DL.asgi:application"
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=DL.production_settings
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/DL/static/
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media_cdn

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/static/
      - media_volume:/media/
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Here's `production_settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/usr/src/app/DL/static/"
```

A snippet of the file structure inside the `web` container (`DL_app` is the name of the Django app):

```
usr
|
|──src
   |
   |──app
      |
      |──DL
         |
         |──DL
         |
         |──DL_app
         |  |
         |  |──static
         |
         |──manage.py
         |
         |──static
```

And, lastly, here's `nginx.conf`:

```
upstream web {
    server web:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/DL/static/;
    }
    location /protected/ {
        alias /media/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mounted static files in `nginx` container at `/static` path:

```yaml
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/static/  # here
```

But your NGINX configuration defines they are at `/usr/src/app/DL/static/`

```
    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/DL/static/; # there is no such path in NGINX container
        #alias /static/;  # this should work
    }
```